# Array in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm currently testing Google Search Console API data with Pandas.

The data is structured like this:

```
'rows': [{
    'impressions': 307.0, 
    'clicks': 79.0, 
    'position': 1.013029315960912}, 
    {'keys': ['spring break 2018', 'https://zrce.eu/partykalender/big-beach-spring-break/']},
    {
    'impressions': 5307.0, 
    'clicks': 179.0, 
    'position': 1.013029315960912}, 
    {'keys': ['spring break zrce', 'https://zrce.eu/partykalender/big-beach-spring-break/']},
    {
    'impressions': 3307.0, 
    'clicks': 759.0, 
    'position': 1.013029315960912}, 
    {'keys': ['spring break 2017', 'https://zrce.eu/partykalender/big-beach-spring-break/']},
    {
    'impressions': 3567.0, 
    'clicks': 749.0, 
    'ctr': 0.25732899022801303, 
    'position': 1.013029315960912}, 
    {'keys': ['zrce', 'https://zrce.eu/']}
]
```

I transform the data to a Pandas dataframe like this:

```
df = json_normalize(jsonfiles, 'rows')
```

My problem is the nested keys array. I want to transform the first value of the array to be in a keyword column and the second to be in an url column.

output should be something like this

```
{
    'impressions': 3567.0, 
    'clicks': 749.0, 
    'ctr': 0.25732899022801303, 
    'position': 1.013029315960912}, 
    'keyword': 'zrce', 
    'url': 'https://zrce.eu/'}, ...
```

something like this is sadly not working

```
df["keyword"]=df["position"][0]
df["url"]=df["position"][0]
```

If I query the API to get just the keyword or url something like this works. The array just has 1 value in this case.

```
df['keyword'] = df['keys'].apply(pd.Series)
```

But with 2 values in the array of course this fails

Comment: Need a couple more "rows" of data before I can figure out how to do this. Can you add that please?

Comment: there you go... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem a little preprocessing is needed to fix your data. Let's combine the adjacent records, so that the data in `keys` is also read in -

```
y = data['rows']
for i, j in zip(y[::2], y[1::2]):
    i.update(dict(zip(['keyword', 'url'], j['keys'])))
```

Now, read in every alternate record in `data` -

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['rows'][::2])
df

   clicks       ctr  impressions            keyword  position  \
0    79.0       NaN        307.0  spring break 2018  1.013029   
1   179.0       NaN       5307.0  spring break zrce  1.013029   
2   759.0       NaN       3307.0  spring break 2017  1.013029   
3   749.0  0.257329       3567.0               zrce  1.013029   

                                                 url  
0  https://zrce.eu/partykalender/big-beach-spring...  
1  https://zrce.eu/partykalender/big-beach-spring...  
2  https://zrce.eu/partykalender/big-beach-spring...  
3                                   https://zrce.eu/
```

Calling `to_dict('r')` on this `df` will give you something like this -

```
[
    {
        "clicks": 79.0,
        "url": "https://zrce.eu/partykalender/big-beach-spring-break/",
        "position": 1.013029315960912,
        "ctr": NaN,
        "impressions": 307.0,
        "keyword": "spring break 2018"
    },
    ...
]
```

Disclaimer! This method will modify your data in place. If you don't want that, I'd recommend making a copy first.